# How to select columns from different tables in 1 query when I don't have a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables in my database:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see my `matches` table contains 2 columns named: `team_id_1` and `team_id_2`, what I want is to select all column from the `matches` table and also get the `team_name_en` and `team_name_ar` from the `teams` table for `team_id_1` and `team_id_2`.

Note that my `matches` table has 1 foreign key: `group_id`

Comment: What do you mean by *...when I don't have a foreign key*? There are 2 columns in `matches` which reference `teams`. Also, why do you mention `group_id`?

Comment: Foreign keys are there to ensure data consistency. They are not needed to join. (But handy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join all tables , teams twice, to get all colums.

```
SELECT 
    m.*, g.*, t1.*, t2.*
FROM
    matches m
        INNER JOIN
    `groups` g ON g.group_id = m.group_id
        INNER JOIN
    teams t1 ON t1.team_id = m.team_id_1
        INNER JOIN
    teams t2 ON t2.team_id = m.team_id_2
```

But you should only join tables, if you need the columns.

also you should only get the columns that are needed. but when you run the query you at least can see how it works